# HBase-Mapreducer, optimal number of reducers when using TableReducer

Tags: mapreduce, connection, hbase, reducers

We are using Map reduce to write data into HBase. Since we have some formatting to be done, we implemented our own reducer by extending TableReducer. This custom reducer is behaving differently in production and development environments. Getting the following error

**Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 659 actions: RegionTooBusyException: 659 times,**

From [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10499), I understood that the flushing is not done properly. However, the same is working fine in dev environment.

Along with the above option, I feel configuring the number of reducers might also effect, how much data is sent to a region server.

We are using salt to span the row keys among the region servers. As of now, salt is 20m and number of region servers are 60. Should the salt be chosen equal to the number of region servers to span the records evenly? If not, how to identify the optimal value for number of reducers, while loading data into Hbase.

Also, in general, what is the maximum number of connections allowed at client side, to interact with Hbase. Here, we are using API provided Map reducer, but in general, we we handle the client connection to Hbase, the maximum number of client connections can play an important role. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hbase-mapreduce API, itself will decide the number of reducers as equal to regional server count. [This](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase-server/0.98.12-hadoop2/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableMapReduceUtil.java#TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Class%2Corg.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job%2Cjava.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29), code base confirms it. So, the problem was, wehn we write our map reduce, we are giving the number of reducers a value, which s different from the default. So, looks like, the default value here shoyuld work well, unless we have a specific requirement.